# Can closed dense sets in the completion space be no longer closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Given a metric space $(E,d)$, where $d$ is the metric, let $T$ refer to the topology in $E$ induced by $d$. Suppose that given $T$, $E$ is closed.

Let $F$ refer to the completion of $E$ with respect to $d$, i.e. $F$ can be formed from the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of $E$, and $(F,d)$ is now the complete metric space with topology $T'$ induced by $d$.

Let $\psi:E \rightarrow F$, be a morphism such that $\psi$ embeds any $x \in E$ to its 'equivalent' element $\psi(x) \in F$, i.e. $\psi(x) = \{x,x,x,x,...\} \in F$

I would like to ask, even if $E$ is closed under $T$, $\psi(E)$ is no longer closed under $T'$ right ?

Comment: What is your favorite example of a metric space and its completion? (Also, $E$ is always closed with respect to $T$ -- the entire space is always a closed set, in any topology.)

Comment: $E$ is always closed in itself. It is dense in its metric completion, so it is closed in its metric completion if and only if it is already complete and is therefore equal to its completion.

Comment: $\psi(E)$ is dense in $F.$ And $\psi(E)=F$ iff $d$ is a complete metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the usual Q and its completion R.
Let p be an irrational point of R.
I = (p - 1, p + 1) is clopen within Q.
Within R, I is open and not closed.